# Writing a dictionary to file only results in keys

Tags: python, dictionary

In this program the output is only showing key but what can i do so that both key and value save in data.txt file

```
myfile = open(r'data.txt','w')
d = {'studentName':'ABC''\n','RollNo':'2'}
myfile.writelines(d)
myfile.close()
```

Comment: What is the output format expected ?

Comment: want o/p like this
studenName:ABC
RollNo:2

Comment: [edit] your post to add the expected output

Answer (score 2):

The best way to serialize this, is to use the JSON format, the content would be the following, and use `json.loads` you'd be able to deserialize the structure in a dict

```
import json

d = {'studentName': 'ABC', 'RollNo': '2'}
with open(r'data.txt', 'w') as myfile:
    myfile.write(json.dumps(d))

# outputs
{"studentName": "ABC", "RollNo": "2"}
```

---

For a custom row by row format, iterate and write each

```
d = {'studentName': 'ABC', 'RollNo': '2'}
with open(r'data.txt', 'w') as myfile:
    for k, v in d.items():
        myfile.write(f"{k}:{v}\n")

# outputs
studentName:ABC
RollNo:2
```

Comment: `myfile.write(f"{k}:{v}\n")`
why have you put f

Comment: @KunalTelangi that is formatting https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/ you can also do `k + "/" + v + "\n"`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
d = {'studentName': 'ABC''\n', 'RollNo': '2'}
with open("data.txt", 'w') as f:
    for key, value in d.items():
        f.write('%s:%s' % (key, value))
```

will give

```
studentName:ABC
RollNo:2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'studentName':'ABC', 'RollNo':'2'}

with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    for key, value in d.items():
        f.write(f'{key} : {value} \n')
```